# Set Log4j 2 property file location without System.setProperty or classpath?

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

i'm moving from Log4j 1.2 to Log4j 2.8 and am looking for a way to set the location of the property file in my programs. In 1.2, this was done using

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("path/to/log4j.properties");
```

However, reading the documentation, the config via property file in 2.8 seems to be restricted to 
a) located in classpath or 
 
b) via System property (see [1](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html))

Since i have some applications where part of the system has its own configuration and needs to load it on demand, i wonder whether there is a way to config the Logmanager during runtime using a properties file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one more way to specify `log4j2` configuration file location -

```
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator.initialize(null, "path/to/log4j2.properties");
```

Only point of precaution is that the [`Configurator`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/Configurator.html) class is not part of the public API. So, it might get removed in future version.

Above code is working in **`log4j2 version 2.8.2`** which is latest.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
    File f = new File("E:/config/log4j2.xml");
    LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    context.setConfigLocation(f.toURI());
```